# WKWebView xhr in phonegap project return status 0 and readyState = 4

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, wkwebview

I am building a Phonegap app and I install the plugin `WKWebView` for iOS platform.

The problem that I am facing now is that when I make a `post` using `xhr` to google to get the access token from a code I get `xhr` return `readyState = 4` and `status = 0`

If I test using `UIWebView` with same code everything is working ok. Also same code on `Android` (without `WKWebView`) is working ok. So this problem is only on `iOS` using `WKWebView`

Here is the post:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    var data = 'code=' + encodeURIComponent(code[1]) +
               '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(this.gdrive_client_id) +
               '&client_secret=' + encodeURIComponent(this.gdrive_client_secret) +
               '&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost' +
               '&grant_type=authorization_code'
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.send(data);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(xhr.status); //Here I get status 0
        }
    };
```

I am using `WKWebView` verison `0.6.4`

`Phonegap` cli version `5.5.2`

Platform: ios `3.9.2`

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView actually respects cross-origin request policies, unlike webview. This is actually more secure, but is a nuisance for phonegap/cordova apps for a myriad of reasons. See [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10144), [amongst](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10109) [others](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10143), for details.